# TDD process explanation

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, phpunit, automated-tests

*I'm new to unit testing and TDD*. I understand how important it is, so I would like to start learning it. The problem is that **I don't see the whole picture in TDD**. By that I mean, how do I do it when I just start a project? I have already played with some tests, testing a method or something, but **how do I do it on a larger scale**, like a whole project?

So please, could someone maybe **write down in bulletpoints or something how do I start**?

Do I test every single class and write tests for every single method, and how can I test my application as a whole, and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I test every single class and write tests for every single methods and how can i test my 
>   application as a hole, and so on and so forth.

Basically, in a perfect world, yes. You may even write multiple tests per method. And test driven means, you start writing tests and then start to development and make the tests pass.

Example:

You are about the write a config file class and want to start using Test Driven Development. So you would start writing the test **before** the implementation:

```
class ConfigFileTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {


    public function testOpen() {
        $config = new ConfigFile(); // 1 .test will fail because the class doesn't exists
        // -> solution write the class
        $this->assertTrue($config->open('test.config')); // 2. test will fail because open isn't implemented yet
        // -> solution: implement open()..

        // and so on ...
    }

}
```

As you see the test may guide you trough implementation and as a special benefit it will keeping useful after implementation as you can use the test to check if the class works as expected even after later changes in the code.

---

However I should tell you about [`behat`](http://behat.org/). It's follows a different approach on testing named 'behaviour driven development'.. You should take at look at.

Comment: i'm aware of BDD but not quite interested in it, at this point, maybe later, when i'll have a better understanding of TDD